# Data storage system with fast access for git

Tags: c#, storage

I am developing a specialized vector graphic editor.

The project file stores all vector shapes and their positions.

Although there may be a lot of shapes in the project, this is not a problem for git when I stored everything in JSON.

But recently I needed the ability to add a 3d model to each figure, usually one model weighs about a megabyte, and the weight of the entire project can reach 100 megabytes.

The software itself does not support editing 3d models, they are stored as a binary data array that will never be changed, the user can only completely replace it with another 3d model.

It's just a parameter in JSON with a string of raw data, the git still handles it well.

The problem is in the software, the fact is that the project file is a kind of library and the user does not need to see everything at once, he selects shapes one by one, but in my case I cannot load only one piece of memory from JSON, the program  has to process the entire project file  before it will be possible to give the user to display the desired shape, and it also loads RAM and also significantly increases the operating time.

Do you have any advice on this? Perhaps there are other data storage systems?

I need to:

1. This storage system could exist as a single file.
2. GIt could work with this.
3. I didn't have to unload the entire project into memory to display only the necessary component

Comment: [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: My question is different, I don't have any problems with storing large files.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase it. Are you looking for a DB? for a format to replace JSON? for a better way to divide your project data to shape files?

Comment: I'll try to reformulate. I need to store a collection of binary files in a single file. The contents of an individual element of the collection do not change, elements can only be added or removed. It looks like an archive where you can add files and delete them, as well as the archive is just one file.

But the git should not read this file as a whole, it should be able to detect changes so that several people can merge branches.


And it works quite successfully for me, I just use JSON and store data in the form of {"key": binary}

Comment: But my application is very heavily loaded when it reads the entire JSON file. I don't need to read everything, just a section with a specific key. I only need to pull out a couple of items. What format/algorithm should I use so that the git successfully reads the file and detects changes, while at the same time so that my program does not have to download the entire file to find the desired element.